# Login via Verisign PIP OpenID not working

Tags: support, openid, login

The actual Versign web page for PIP appears to be down: https://pip.verisignlabs.com/.  Does anyone know if this service is going away from Verisign?  Or is the Verisign site down?

Comment: <sigh> down again. Hey OP - want to start recording the occurrences of significant outages? Could be useful to see and makes this post more useful.

Comment: Down for me, yet again.  Luckily, I have an alternate login for Stack Overflow.  I think it's finally time for me to ditch Verisign's OpenID.  What's the point of it, if it's not reliable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too use Verisign PIP. I didn't receive any notice they were discontinuing the service, so I assume this is a temporary outage.

From the informational PDF about PIP:

> For more information about VeriSign Identity Protection, 
>   please call 650-426-5310 or email: identityandauthenticationservices@verisign.com.

<strike>I'm emailing them now to ask about this outage and will update this answer when I hear back.</strike>

Apparently they're aware of the issue. The site now says:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: Thanks for the feedback that I wasn't the only one.

Comment: Sure thing. Looks like it's back now, too.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I get "An Unexpected Problem Has Occurred" when I try to log in

Answer (score 3):

There may have been an outage but it appears to be up now:

http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/pip.verisignlabs.com/

Answer (score 0):

This was posted on @VeriSign on Tweeter several hours ago (~10:30 EDT?)

> pip.verisignlabs.com will be taken out of service temporarily due to network reconfiguration #verisign @openID #PIP

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any other info about how much longer or the specific reason for the outage.  I choose Verisign over MyOpenId - I was thinking it would be more reliable.  Now I'm very concerned now about the length and the lack of communication about this Verisign outage.

If you're not already using it, consider using [OpenID delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466608/openid-delegation) to hopefully ease changing providers, if necessary (knock on wood).

Comment: Thanks for the update! I do use OpenID delegation. This is only the second issue I've had with PIP in as many years, normally they're rock solid.

Comment: My main issue was that I hadn't associated my google openId with my Area51 account, and couldn't login there.  I'll always have to make sure I have a backup, although it doesn't sound like this happens too often.