# Unable to authenticate via OpenID with pip.verisignlabs.com

Tags: support, login, openid

As of late I can't login with `pip.verisignlabs.com` as my OpenID provider. I've replaced my actual username in the error message with `username`.

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>     The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match.

```
Assertion endpoint info: 
ClaimedIdentifier: http://username.pip.verisignlabs.com/
ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://username.pip.verisignlabs.com/
ProviderEndpoint: https://pip.verisignlabs.com/server
OpenID version: 2.0
Service Type URIs: 
Discovered endpoint info: [
{
    ClaimedIdentifier: http://username.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://username.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderEndpoint: http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server
    OpenID version: 2.0
    Service Type URIs:
        http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon
        http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
        http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/phishing-resistant
        http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/multi-factor
        http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/multi-factor-physical
},
{
    ClaimedIdentifier: http://username.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://username.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderEndpoint: http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server
    OpenID version: 1.1
    Service Type URIs:
        http://openid.net/signon/1.1
        http://openid.net/sreg/1.0
        http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
}
,]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen from time to time, when using Verisign as an OpenID provider. It happened on SE sites, twice, in 2010:

- **[Verisign login not working at SO/SF/etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131211/verisign-login-not-working-at-so-sf-etc)**
- **[Login to SO via Verisign failing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48022/login-to-so-via-verisign-failing)**

and again in 2012, and maybe a few more times. In each case, it seems that other StackExchange users were affected, and often, that 
**[Symantec user support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131382/160875)**
**[needed to be involved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48296/160875)**. Here's their contact info, from **[Verisign help document](http://www.verisign.com/static/043732.pdf)** [PDF], unchanged since 2010:

> For more information about VeriSign Identity Protection, please call
>   650-426-5310 or email: identityandauthenticationservices@verisign.com.

I have a Verisign ID, but haven't associated it with StackExchange and all my other OpenID providers, would rather keep them separate, else I would try to see if I'm having the same difficulty. **[Verisign OpenID](https://pip.verisignlabs.com/)** is not down, so that isn't the problem (**[it was once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66172/login-via-verisign-pip-openid-not-working)**, in a past question on MSO).

*** I should have written this as a comment, but it is way too lengthy.

Comment: Thanks I've written an email to them, lets see what they can do.

Comment: Are you serious, they STILL haven't fixed this yet?! That's awful. I nagged them on Twitter a little when you first posted the question. I can nag at them a little bit more now. I would have thought they'd be more attentive to your concerns (though not because of my nagging ;o) I wonder why they were so responsive when this happened on SO in the past, but not now?

Comment: Yes no answer to my mail and it is still not working.